# Grails 3 - Scaffolding with Id showing in list

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to get the "id" of a domain to show when listing a domain (with the index action of the scaffolding) using dynamic views?

It looks like the columns are based off constraints, but adding "id" to the constraints causes various errors depending on how I add the id to the constraints:

```
id()
id
id nullable: false
```

I know I can make static views as a workaround, but I'd very much prefer to use dynamic views so that they're easier to maintain with future Grails upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by making a small change to the scaffolding plugin templates. You will need to install the default templates into your project by using the [install-templates](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) command.

Once you have your templates installed open /src/main/templates/scaffolding/index.gsp and find the line that reads

```
<f:table collection="\${${propertyName}List}" />
```

This is the line that generates the table on the list (index) view. You can customize the columns shown in the generated table by adding a properties list containing the desired fields to be rendered in the table. For example,

```
<f:table collection="\${${propertyName}List}" properties="['id', 'bar', 'baz']" />
```

The drawback is that this will change the table generation for all interfaces. To get around this copy the index.gsp file to views/*controllerName*/index.gsp and make your modifications there.

The  tag is part of the [Fields](https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/%20%22Grails%20Fields%20Plugin%20Documentation) plugin.

Comment: You can also do this: <f:table collection="${configList}" except="[]"/>